# Zuul routing in microservices

Tags: spring, microservices, jhipster, netflix-zuul

I am trying to access a microservice endpoint through a gateway using jhipster. The end point is from a legacy system and starts with "/d" and cannot be modified. I want the gateway to route all the requests that start with '/d/** ' to my microservice where I have a rest controller that will handle the requests that is mapped to '/api/d/**'

I'm trying to work using the documentation, so I have in my gateway the route:

```
zuul:
    routes:
        my-service-route:
              path:/d/**
              serviceId: serviceName
```

I saw that using url in zuul configuration you can specify the url directly, but I use jhipster registry so I can't approach the problem like that. As far as I understand I have to write a custom Zuul Filter or a Zuul Route Configuration that will route the requests to my service.

So I have 2 problems:

1. I can't access the gateway if I use a rest that begins with /d
2. I can't route the requests to my microservice in the way that I expect:
   /d/service to be routed to my microservice where I have a restcontroller with a mapping to "/d/service".

Any info on how I should approach this is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I already added my path in WebConfig `source.registerCorsConfiguration("/d/**", config);` and in SecurityConfiguration `.antMatchers("/d/**").authenticated()`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this below configuration in application.properties also you can change it to yml accordingly. so any request coming as /d/* will redirect to **serviceName** application instance.

```
zuul.routes.serviceName.serviceId=serviceName
zuul.routes.serviceName.path=/d/**
zuul.routes.serviceName.sensitive-headers=Set-Cookie,Authorization
hystrix.command.serviceName.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=600000
```

Comment: I tried something like this, but the problem is that the application generated by jhipster has default access endpoint set on /api. So any other access endpoint that doesn't start with /api will automatically be rejected. I tried to modify the SecurityConfiguration for allowing me to access the backend on /d, but I had no success with it yet.